# Discord bot errors

Tags: discord, discord.py, pytube

Code:

```
@client.command()
async def downloadmp4(ctx, link):
    yt = pytube.YouTube(link)
    video = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').order_by('resolution').desc().first()
    out_file = video.download(output_path='C:\\Users\\Ethan\\PycharmProjects\\YoutubeBot')
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(out_file)
    new_file = base + '.mp4'
    os.rename(out_file, new_file)
    await ctx.channel.send(file=discord.File(new_file))
    os.remove(new_file)
```

Error:

```
[2022-11-08 21:46:32] [ERROR   ] discord.ext.commands.bot: Ignoring exception in command downloadmp4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\PycharmProjects\YoutubeBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 190, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\*****\PycharmProjects\YoutubeBot\test.py", line 51, in downloadmp4
    await ctx.channel.send(file=discord.File(new_file))
  File "C:\Users\*****\PycharmProjects\YoutubeBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1536, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, params=params)
  File "C:\Users\*****\PycharmProjects\YoutubeBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 744, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 413 Payload Too Large (error code: 40005): Request entity too large

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\PycharmProjects\YoutubeBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1347, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\*****\PycharmProjects\YoutubeBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 986, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\*****\PycharmProjects\YoutubeBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 199, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 413 Payload Too Large (error code: 40005): Request entity too large
```

I'm trying to make a discord bot convert a youtube video to a file then send it. It isn't working. Ive tried changing up a load of things, but i really cant figure it out.

Comment: I think the answer to your problem is in the error message. You are receiving a 413 status code which means that the request entity is larger than limits defined by the server. Not exactly sure how to fix it right now, but its where I would start.

Comment: The maximum file size limit is 8MB, so you have to either compress the file somehow, or maybe chop it up into multiple parts. Both are not ideal obviously but you cannot circumvent the limit otherwise.